# Assume cd when no command is specified and the first argument is a directory

Tags: bash, cd

Is it possible in bash to automatically `cd` into a directory even without typing `cd`?

E.g., I'd like to be able to `cd` into `./whatever` when just typing the following into the terminal:

```
./whatever
```

Is there a way to achieve this with bash? I know that zsh supports this.

One of my thoughts was to catch the *Is a directory* error thrown by bash when just typing `./whatever` and subsequently cd into that directory but I couldn't find out a way to do it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=bash+cd+to+directory+without+cd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just enable the shell option `autocd`:

```
shopt -s autocd
```

From the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

> `autocd`
>
> If set, a command name that is the name of a directory is executed as if it were the argument to the `cd` command. This option is only used by interactive shells.